# Android SQLite view database

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there a possibility when a change occurs in the database from within my emulator. That it can also automatically update the same database on my pc (local)?

Because now I'm doing it this way:

1. I'm opening cmd
2. And then I'm getting my database file through the
       following command:

   adb pull /data/data/com.XXX.module/databases/com.XXX.module. database/Users/somePathOnYourPC/

Each time when I'm making a change in the database from within my emulator. So if I want to view that database in SqliteBrowser on my pc. Then each time I have to execute the above command.

Comment: i dont know if theres a way to do it, but you can just create a .bat file on your desktop with these commands, and opening the database, so you get everything with one click.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for your advice I have tried what you told me, but I'm stuck. I have made a question about it on Stackoverflow. If you want to see it here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617171/cant-execute-batch-file

Comment: don't use quotes
i guess 
cd C:/Users/yomac_000/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platform-tools
adb pull /data/data/com.XXX.module/databases/com.XXX.module database/Users/somePathOnYourPC/
should do the first step.